# Why is the javascript variable undefined? (2nd time around...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reposting this question with revised code that use more of jQuery.

Here is the HTML code that defines the objects:

```
<LEGEND><b>Select Study Sample</b></LEGEND>
<p>
<P CLASS=select_header>Study - Box - Well - Lab ID<br>
<SELECT multiple size=20 NAME="stylabid" ID="stylabid" onchange=show_stylabid() onclick=clear_fetch() STYLE="width: 115px">
<?php 
  $i=0;
  while ($i < $numstylabids) {
    $styarr = pg_fetch_row($stylabidresult);
    echo "<option value=$styarr[0]>$styarr[1]\n";
    $i++;           
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

and

```
<LEGEND><b>Select Project Sample</b></LEGEND>
<p>
<P CLASS=select_header>Project - Box - Well - Lab ID<br>
<SELECT multiple size=20 NAME="pjtlabid" ID="pjtlabid" onchange=show_pjtlabid() onclick=clear_fetch() STYLE="width: 115px">
<?php 
  $j=0;
  while ($j < $numpjtlabids) {
    $pjtarr = pg_fetch_row($pjtlabidresult);
    echo "<option value=$pjtarr[0]>$pjtarr[1]\n";
    $j++;           
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

Now, here is the javascript; I am simply trying to get the values of the selected object, which can be either a Study or a Project. I use this later to retrieve data from the database:

```
function fetchgenotype() {
    var ms, mndx, ss, sndex = 0;

    ms = $("#marker")[0].selectedIndex;    

    if (Study_selected) {
      ss = $("#stylabid")[0].selectedIndex;
      sndx = $("#stylabid").val(ss);
    } else
      ss = $("#pjtlabid")[0].selectedIndex;
      sndx = $("#pjtlabid").val(ss);
    }    

    // for debugging...    
 alert('ss='+ss+', sndx='+sndx);
```

This code dies on the line `sndx = ...`  Would really appreciate any help!

TIA

Comment: sndx was never defined. Pretty much what undefined means. From the looks of this, you know better! :) (p.s. - define sndx or use sndex)

Comment: When is that function being called? I don't see any references to it in the rest of what you've posted.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *This code dies on the line `sndx = ...`* That line shouldn't be causing any errors, even if it doesn't actually return what you expect it to.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to assign sndx?  You know .val(value) is a setter method right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently i don't know what $("#marker") an Study_selected are.

Assuming there is anything OK so far, change the function into:

```
if (Study_selected) {
      sndx = $("#stylabid").val();
    } else
      sndx = $("#pjtlabid").val();
    }
```

`val()` returns the value of a form-element when used without an argument, otherwise it will set the value and return an jQuery-object.

There is no need to retrieve the selectedIndex, you may access the value of the select-element directly(it will be the value of the currently selected option)

Comment: Thanks Dr Molle; that explains a lot. No, I did not know the diff between setter and getter jQ methods; still learning!

Comment: I modified my code per your suggestion:    if (Study_selected) {
      //ss = $("#stylabid")[0].selectedIndex;
      sndx = $('#stylabid').val();
    } else
      //ss = $("#pjtlabid")[0].selectedIndex;
      sndx = $('#pjtlabid').val();
    } ........ but this line throws an error and now Firebug tells me 'TypeError: $ is not a function' [what the heck does that mean? This is standard jQ notation!]

Comment: When $ is not a function it may be that you didn't include jQuery.

Comment: I appreciate all the help I got here, but finally saw the error: the if else statement was missing a bracket between else and sndx...duh! Never underestimate the potential to overlook stupid mistakes....;>

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a syntax error

sndx  should be sndex .. or the other way around

```
var ms, mndx, ss, sndex = 0; // <--

$("#pjtlabid").val(ss) // <-- setter method
```

.val(value) is also a setter method so sndx is undefined because it never was defined with any value

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo:

```
var ms, mndx, ss, sndex = 0;
```

should be

```
var ms, mndx, ss, sndx = 0;
```

Comment: Calling `sndx = ...` will happily declare a global variable, even if `sndx` is undefined prior to that. The typo may cause problems, but it isn't the cause of *this* problem, assuming all of the information in the question is correct.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist no... it will be local to the scope due to the `var` keyword.

Comment: @KevinB There isn't a `var` keyword in the code in the question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It's right here, `var ms, mndx, ss, sndex = 0;` copied from the OP. It's also in Adrian's answer.

Comment: @KevinB Right, `sndex` (with an e), and we're talking about a declaration for `sndx` (no e).